# Getting Postfix to pass SMTP AUTH to after queue content filter

Tags: smtp, postfix-mta, smtp-auth

I am using a Postfix after queue content filter to filter incoming and outgoing email. Postfix injects each mail to the content filter using SMTP. Then the content filter scans the mail and re-injects the message back into postfix just like here:

http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html#advanced_filter

My master.cf file looks like this:

```
## After Queue Content Filter
filter      unix  -       -       n       -       10      smtp
            -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
            -o disable_mime_output_conversion=yes
            -o smtp_generic_maps=
            -o myhostname=sample.hostname.com

## Re-injection listener
reinject unix  n       -       n       -       10      smtpd
    -o content_filter=
    -o receive_override_options=no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_header_body_checks,no_milters
    -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
    -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
    -o smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts=127.0.0.0/8
```

Now, this works as expected and everything seems great.... Except..
I need to know if an email was sent using SMTP Authentication or not.
Now, using the smtp_send_xforward_command=yes gives me a lot of information about the remote sender, but, nothing about whether or not the email has been authenticated. Is there any way to get Postfix to tell my content filter if an email has been sent by an authenticated user and if so, which user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

[smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header=yes](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header)

to add a username to the Received header and the content filter can parse that to determine authentication.

Comment: Wow.. That actually works. My only concern is this... Since this is simply a header that postfix adds. I would think it is possible for any server to add the same header and therefore lead my content filter to believe that an email has been authenticated when it in fact has not, or maybe it was authenticated by a different server. What are your thoughts as to verifying the validity of the header and whether or not it was added by MY postfix server and not some other server?

Comment: Assuming this is inbound messages, you should only be checking the top-most Received header which should be from your server.

Comment: I am checking incoming and outgoing. If I was only checking incoming, there would be no SMTP auth unless a user was sending locally. So, that being said though, I don't think it is any different for outgoing, right? Am I to assume that my server will always add the top most received header whether a user was smtp authorized or not? I guess I need to test that....

Comment: It seems that my server always adds the top Received header... So this is a header I can trust. It's either authenticated or not.... Thanks. Cheers.